# How do order a ggplot barplot with ONE variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I reorder the bars if I am using just one variable?

```
cbp2 <- c("#44bcd8", "#b97455", "#042f66", "#1c100b",
      "#ff3300", "#006600", "#660033", "#660066","#ffcc00","#99ff99","#669999")
ggplot(data = diamonds)+
geom_bar(mapping = aes(color, fill=cut))+ 
theme(aspect.ratio = 1) +
scale_fill_manual(values = cbp2)+ 
labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)+ 
coord_flip()
```

I get this:
[image: Bar plot]

To reoder, I tried to use `geom_bar(mapping = aes(x=reorder(color, fill=cut))`

but it doesn't work. Tried to look on the web but all examples include both x and y in `aes()`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Error: `Error in tapply(X = X, INDEX = x, FUN = FUN, ...) : 
  argument "X" is missing, with no default`

Comment: What order do you expect?

Comment: This must throw an error: `reorder(color, fill=cut)` since `fill` is not a `reorder` argument.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure what order you wish to re-order `x` to, but `fct_reorder` (from `forcats` library) accepts a range of helpful functions.

Key point: wrap only the mapped variable you wish to reorder in `fct_reorder` - in your example above you have included fill in the `reorder` call.

If you wish to reorder by the count of each colour:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

ggplot(data = diamonds)+
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(fct_reorder(color, cut, .fun = 'length'), fill=cut))+ 
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cbp2)+ 
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)+ 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

More examples here: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/267-reorder-a-variable-in-ggplot2.html

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Hadn't come cross the `forcats` library before. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Used the library `forcats` and the function `fct_rec()`

```
library(forcats)
library(ggplot2)
cbp2 <- c("#44bcd8", "#b97455", "#042f66", "#1c100b",
      "#ff3300", "#006600", "#660033", "#660066","#ffcc00","#99ff99","#669999")

ggplot(data = diamonds)+
geom_bar(mapping = aes(fct_rev(color), fill=cut))+ 
theme(aspect.ratio = 1) +
scale_fill_manual(values = cbp2)+ 
labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Daniel, thanks for your answer. unfortunately, it doesn't work. But it's okay as the first answer using `forcats`.